# Como alterar o método de uma requisição HTTP no Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel

Preciso realizar operações de CRUD em determinados locais da minha aplicação que estão contidos dentro de outros formularios. Para isso irei utilizar AJAX para atualizar as views contendo o "sub-conteúdo'.

Estou utilizando os métodos de `Resource Controllers` do Laravel 4 para controlar as rotas a partir dos metodos padrão do Framework:

[image: Actions Resource Controller]

Para exemplificar melhor o cenário: Existe um cadastro de empresas que possui n pessoas atribuídas a esta empresa.

A view `cadastro.empresas.edit` tem um formulario com os dados da empresa e dentro dessa view tenho uma div que irá trabalhar as pessoas sendo atualizado pelo AJAX de acordo com as operações de CRUD.

**O problema:**
Quando faço um `return Redirect::action('PessoasController@show', array('id' => $pessoa->id));` preciso que o método da requisição seja um `GET`, porem como a requisição original (update) é um `PUT` acabo caindo num loop infinito.

Como faço para indicar qual método desejo utilizar ao chamar um `Redirect::action()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que seu problema não é o laravel pois o método

```
Redirect::route('rota.pessoa.show, $pessoa->id);
```

Funciona normal aqui em minhas aplicações laravel 4.1,
a sua questão ai é que está tentando fazer um redirect dentro um request AJAX,
que estaria esperando apenas uma resposta.

Duas dicas, ou você devolve um "OK" pra esse request, e após receber o OK você faz a chamada do método show, ou então faz essa implementação, usando algo como AngularJS ou BackboneJS.

Comment: Realmente @Allan Freitas, por falta de conhecimento insisti em aguardar o Redirect. Alterei o codigo para que trabalhe da forma como você sugeriu e está funcionando. Agora só preciso deixá-lo mais "enxuto", pois não fico muito confortavel em deixar esse tipo de coisa no frontend. De qualquer forma muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

> Tente usar `Redirect::route('rota.pessoa.show, $pessoa->id)`

Fica mais fácil de dar manutenção e ler.
Sempre nomeio minhas rotas, mesmo não usando resource, e nunca tive um problema parecido com o cenário que você indicou.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @vinicius73, porem ja havia tentado usar rota nomeada. Analisando as requisições ele envia o redirect como PUT. Estou usando: `if (Request::ajax()){return Redirect::route('cadastro.pessoas.show', $pessoa->id);}` no controller. Alguma outra sugestão?